# Не загружаются изображения через Glide

Tags: android, memory, сборщик-мусора, glide

Думается мне, что опытные товарищи в своё время сталкивались с тем, что не выводятся изображения, спарсенные с сайта например, т.к. вся галерея занимает много мегабайт.
Вот мой адаптер:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    private List<PhotoCard> photocardList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView photo;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            photo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        }

    }

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, List<PhotoCard> photocardList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.photocardList = photocardList;
        }

        @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbs, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PhotoCard photocardItem = photocardList.get(position);
        ImageView imageView = holder.photo;

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(photocardItem.getPhoto())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.temp_img)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(imageView);
        }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photocardList.size();
    }
}
```

Вот логи после открытия одной галерей, выбранной из списка(recyclerview):

```
12-07 22:40:17.204 14094-14094/ru.alexandrpokh.cheltanks I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:ru.alexandrpokh.cheltanks time:14744848
12-07 22:40:17.495 14094-14094/ru.alexandrpokh.cheltanks I/ActivityManager: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e705b8 time:14745133
12-07 22:40:17.765 14094-14315/ru.alexandrpokh.cheltanks D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1702K, 30% free 12532K/17756K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
```

Судя по монитору памяти утечки нет. Как я понимаю, создаётся слишком большой объект, который глайд не может переварить, запускается сборщик мусора. Так как быть?

Есть один момент. До глайда использовал ImageLoader, взятый из какого-то примера в сети. Один раз галеря загрузилась, но всё было очень медленно. Больше галерея не загружалась.После принято решение перейти на глайд.

Вот что выдавал лог при ImageLoader'е:

```
MemoryCache will use up to 24.0MB
```

Увеличение кэша, поправкой в коде этого лоадера, результата не дало.

p.s. если нужен ещё какой код, то выложу

Comment: Пермиш добавил? Это звучит смешно, но помню я час потратил на решение подобной проблемы. Пока не вспомнил, что забыл разрешение прописать в манифесте :)

Comment: Да, конечно, всё добавлено)

Comment: @YaPV , какая проблема была у вас?

Comment: Проблема была с загрузкой картинок в ImageView. Перелопатил куски кода и понять не мог, в чем дело. Ну а потом вспомнил, что пермишн не прописал в манифесте))

Comment: @YaPV Так всё, решил проблему почти) совсем забыл про  `gAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
Но возникла новая проблема:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load on a null Context`

Comment: Так инициализируй контекст в адаптере при создании. Судя по ошибке :)